# Dom book which introduces DOM as much as possible?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to read a book that systematically introduces dom with live examples.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dom Scripting](http://domscripting.com/book/) was an interesting book, taught me a lot about JavaScript.

Comment: It's a good book,but will be better if there is more about how to use css to make the page look nicer.

Comment: @Shore: But wouldn't that be better off in a separate CSS book?

Answer (score 1):

its going to be hard to find a book that specifically focuses on the dom (maybe an intense xml book). You want the dom and the dom features with javascript I assume.  [check out oreilly's more advanced javascript book.](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101992/) I actually have the book right here, there's a good 34 pages on the dom with examples; its a complete reference for all of javascript, so about 1000 pages in all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [jQuery](http://jquery.com)? I know you're asking for tutorials on accessing the DOM directly, but jQuery offers a much simplier way that allows you to never worry about browser differences.

Comment: while jQuery is great, I don't think it's a substitute for knowing how the DOM works

Answer (score 0):

Javascript the definitive guide by david flanagan, current edition 5th